# UIView animation of size

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a custom UIView (with its outlets and constraints) that I want to animate, so I used .animateWithDuration function to change its position.

After changing the position I want to change the width of the view in the animation block, so:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0) {
        self.myView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
    }
```

This code changes the width but it does it in not an elegant way:

It seems to knows the final width, set it without animating (but clipping the content to the primary bounds) and then expands the width (so it reveals what was hidden).

It does look awful, as I have for example my labels text centered, so the text just jumps from primary position to the final one and then there is the animation.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: You are animating widths when using auto layout at the same time? That will not work properly, you should animate the constraints instead.

Comment: But the window itself does not have any constraints. Only its subviews have.

Comment: Maybe you could try using `layoutIfNeeded` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutIfNeeded